# sed regex expression replace

Tags: regex, xml, bash, sed, xml-namespaces

I have a config.xml file that has this line in it:

```
<widget id="com.FitDegree.SOMETHING" version="5.1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

Using a bash script, I need to replace com.FitDegree.SOMETHING with a string such as com.FitDegree.ThisIsIt

The closest I can get is this:

```
  sed -r 's/\"com\.FitDegree\..+?\"/"com.FitDegree.ThisIsIt"/' ../config.xml > tmpfile
  mv tmpfile ../config.xml
```

but it results in:

```
<widget id="com.FitDegree.ThisIsIt">
```

Note: it got rid of all the other things in that line such as version, xmlns etc.

When I test it on a regex tester: https://regex101.com/r/nI8xB8/1 it only selects the com.FitDegree.SOMETHING

Any clue how to fix this?

Comment: That's a job for xmlstarlet.

Comment: `sed` doesn't know how to do non-greedy matching.  You probably want a character class like: `'s/\"com\.FitDegree\.[^"]+\"/"com.FitDegree.ThisIsIt"/'`

Comment: @0x5453 that was the solution! Thank you -- make this a proper answer and I'll mark it correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way with **`xmlstarlet`** tool:

```
xmlstarlet ed -N ns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" \
-u '//ns:widget/@id' -v 'com.FitDegree.ThisIsIt' config.xml
```

Comment: Thanks! Only thing i had to change was put it on one line and remove the \ at the end of the first line.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a sed character class, with a backreference for simplicity:

```
sed -e 's/\(\"com\.FitDegree\.\)[^"]*/\1ThisIsIt/' ../config.xml
```

If you have the option available, you can edit the file in place:

```
sed -i -e 's/\(\"com\.FitDegree\.\)[^"]*/\1ThisIsIt/' ../config.xml
```

BTW, Perl handles regular expressions considerably more easily, and this would be:

```
perl -pe 's/("com\.FitDegree\.).*?"/\1ThisIsIt"/' ../config.xml
```

And to edit in place:

```
perl -i -pe 's/("com\.FitDegree\.).*?"/\1ThisIsIt"/' ../config.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a risky regex, but often you know, whether the risk is real or only a thinkable one, since the dot matches dots too:

```
sed 's,com.FitDegree.SOMETHING,com.FitDegree.OtherThing,' sample-2.xml
```

Your .+\" is greedy and takes the last " as delimiter it can. 
To make it work, you could define a non matching group for everything, except quotes:

```
sed -r 's/\"com\.FitDegree\.[^"]+?"/"com.FitDegree.ThisIsIt"/'
#                           ^^^^  ^no masking needed
```